# CheckBox implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to have a checkbox for my Online_Ballot, where a checkbox contains of candidates where a voter could vote for a specific candidates.

Below is my code.

**CandidatesViewModel.cs**

```
public class CandidatesViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<candidates> AvailableCandidates { get;set; }
    public IEnumerable<Candidates> SelectedCandidates { get; set; }
    public PostedCandidates PostedCandidates { get; set; }
}

public class PostedCandidates
{
    public string[] CandidatesId { get; set; }
}
```

**Candidates.cs**

```
public class Candidates
{
    public int candidates_info_id { get; set; }
    public string candidates_fullname { get; set; }
    public object Tags { get; set; }  
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Votation(PostedCandidates PostedCandidates)
{
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(x => x.PostedCandidates.CandidatesId,  
                  x => x.AvailableCandidates,      
                  x => x.candidates_info_id,                    
                  x => x.candidates_fullname,                
                  x => x.SelectedCandidates)
```

But when I tried to run this code, an error is displayed:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   does not contain a definition for 'PostedCandidates' and no extension
>   method 'PostedCandidates' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Comment: Change the Parameter name of Votation

Comment: Post the code for whole view. I think the problem is with the code that you did not post here.

Comment: @model IEnumerable<Online_Ballot.Models.CandidatesViewModel>

Comment: I add this in my view:@model IEnumerable<Online_Ballot.Models.CandidatesViewModel>@using MvcCheckBoxList.Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring model of type `IEnumerable<Online_Ballot.Models.CandidatesViewModel>` and using it like you are having an instance not a collection.

you either need to change your model declaration to following (assuming you are passing single instance of type CandidatesViewModel to view from controller):

```
@model Online_Ballot.Models.CandidatesViewModel
```

or you can change checkbox list generation to something like this (assuming you are passing collection to the view from controller and that collection is having only one element).

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(x => x.FirstOrDefault().PostedCandidates.CandidatesId,  
              x => x.FirstOrDefault().AvailableCandidates,      
              x => x.FirstOrDefault().candidates_info_id,                    
              x => x.FirstOrDefault().candidates_fullname,                
              x => x.FirstOrDefault().SelectedCandidates)
```

Although I would recommend you to go with change model declaration.

**Update**

I also noticed you are not passing instance of your view model to view.

```
public ActionResult Votation(PostedCandidates PostedCandidates)
{
    CandidatesViewModel vm = new CandidatesViewModel();
    //process or fill your viewmodel here.
    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: When I run the program, it returns a null value.

Comment: @JenalynParagados as my answer assumes you need to pass instance of your viewmodel to the view. `CandidatesViewModel vm = new CandidatesViewModel();` and then pass instance of that viewmodel to view method like `return view(vm);`.

Comment: Is CheckBoxFor should be  a boolean type value?